# Overlaying a new library distribution in a Subversion repository

Tags: svn, distribution

I have a Subversion repository with a series of third party libraries and sources. As new distributions of these libraries become available I want to completely replace the old version with the new. What's the best method to "overlay" a new drop of a directory on top of the older one?

Answer (score 1):

The only "clever" way to do it would be to use svn:external properties.